# Oracle - iterate over tables and check for values in attribute

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

For all tables in X, while X is

```
select table_name from all_tab_cols
where column_name = 'MY_COLUMN'
and owner='ADMIN'
```

I need to check, if the column MY_COLUMN has other values than 'Y' or 'N' and if it does, print out the table name.

Pseudo code:

```
for table in X:
    if MY_COLUMN !='Y' or MY_COLUMN !='N':
        print table
```

How to implement that in PL/SQL, with cursors I guess?

Comment: Implement looping through the table names, or implement checking column values, or both?

Comment: iterating over all tables, which are returned by the given sql and check the column value of MY_COLUMN. Each of the tables has this column.

Comment: You could iterate over all the tables with a `for` loop using an implicit cursor, within which you could query the tables with a `SELECT COUNT(*)` in an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement with the `INTO` clause pointing to an integer variable. If the integer > 0, print table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following should work:

```
DECLARE
  counter NUMBER;
  cursor c1 is 
    select table_name from all_tab_cols
    where column_name = 'MY_COLUMN'
    and owner='ADMIN';

BEGIN
  FOR rec IN c1 LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.table_name);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) into :counter from '|| rec.table_name ||' where MY_COLUMN!= ''Y'' and MY_COLUMN!= ''N'' ';
    if counter > 0 then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.table_name);
    end if;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Basically we open a cursor with all tables containing that column, do a count for rows that have different values than Y or N, and if that count > 0, print the table.

Answer (score 0):

The version of Wouter does not work for me. 
Had to remove the semicolon (Oracle Database version 11.2.0.4.0 )

`DECLARE
    counter NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        select count(*) into counter from LASTID;
        dbms_output.put_line(counter);
    END;
    /`